# Alternative of async:false

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous, promise

I need to make an AJAX call in my for loop. I requirement is the calls should be in sequence because I am storing the response in array and the element of array should be in sequence. I had to go for `async: false` as I tried multiple things suggested on many similar questions. None of them worked. Making `async: false` is a really bad Idea which I know, but what are the alternatives of getting the response in sequence?

Additional information: I am mapping the array to my render elements, so few methods I tried gave me error saying "cannot read map of undefined".

Here is what I am currently doing:

```
auto_video_jobs_array = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.state.current_auto_video_jobs_urls.length; i++) {
            this.get_auto_video_jobs_array(i)
        }

get_auto_video_jobs_array(i) {
        var that = this;
        var settings_3 = {
            "async": false,   //this is made false to get array element in right sequence
            "crossDomain": true,
            "url": that.state.current_auto_video_jobs_urls[i],
            "method": "GET",
            "headers": {
                Authorization: "Token " + that.props.token_Reducer.token
            },
            success: function (response, textStatus, jQxhr) {
                console.log("success")
                console.log("value of i is " + i)
            },
        }

        $.ajax(settings_3).done((response) => {
            auto_video_jobs_array.push(response)
            if (i == that.state.current_auto_video_jobs_urls.length - 1) {
                console.log("i reached last value")
                that.setState({current_auto_video_jobs: auto_video_jobs_array})
                console.log("current jobs are" + that.state.current_auto_video_jobs)
            }
        });
    }
```

This what I tried to implement as alternative but it didn't work and threw error saying cannot read map of undefined

```
//initialize index counter
            var i = 0;
            var that = this;
            function next() {
                $.ajax({
                    async: true,
                    "crossDomain": true,
                    "url": that.state.current_auto_video_jobs_urls[i],
                    "method": "GET",
                    "headers": {
                        Authorization: "Token " + that.props.token_Reducer.token
                    },
                    success: function(response, textStatus, jQxhr){
                        ++i;
                        if(i >= that.state.current_auto_video_jobs_urls.length) {
                            // run function here as its the last item in array
                            console.log("i reached last value")
                            that.setState({current_auto_video_jobs: auto_video_jobs_array})
                            console.log("current jobs are" + that.state.current_auto_video_jobs)
                        } else {
                            // do the next ajax call
                            auto_video_jobs_array.push(response)
                            next();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            // start the first one
           next();
```

I need a way to make the async call in a way that I get response in incremental sequence. Promise is one option suggested. I am new to that. If that is the way then how to implement it?

Comment: Do you actually  need to send the requests sequentially? or do you just need the results to be in the original order.

Comment: @KevinB Based on the explanation, seems like they just need to be in the original order.

Answer (score -2):

So basically you need to run a bunch of asynchronous tasks in series. In other words you need to have a kind of [async.series](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#series) method from corresponding library. There is [standalone package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-series) that provides similar functionality, you can take its (pretty small) [sources](https://github.com/hughsk/async-series/blob/master/index.js) as a base for your own solution.

Here is slightly modified version of `async-series` sources with cleaned up code that is specific to node.js environment:

```
/**
 * @author Hugh Kennedy
 * @url https://github.com/hughsk/async-series
 * @license MIT
 */
function series(arr, ready, safe) {
    var length = arr.length, orig;
    var nextTick = 'undefined' !== typeof setImmediate ? setImmediate : setTimeout;

    if (!length) {
        return nextTick(ready, 1)
    }

    function handleItem(idx) {
        arr[idx](function (err) {
            if (err) return ready(err)
            if (idx < length - 1) return handleItem(idx + 1)
            return ready()
        })
    }

    if (safe) {
        orig = handleItem
        handleItem = function (idx) {
            nextTick(function () {
                orig(idx)
            }, 1)
        }
    }

    handleItem(0)
}
```

Having such function it should be easy for you to pass list of tasks to run and fill your array, they're guaranteed to be run sequentially.

Comment: I don't understand a line of this.

Answer (score -2):

Very simple to do this with promises. Be aware that IE does not have built-in support for promises, but you can support them in IE by using a library like Bluebird:

```
var that = this;
var auto_video_jobs_array;

// wait for all promises
Promise.all(this.state.current_auto_video_jobs_urls.map(function (url) {
    // map each url to a promise for the result of querying that URL
    var settings_3 = {
      "crossDomain": true,
      "url": url,
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {
        Authorization: "Token " + that.props.token_Reducer.token
      }
    };

    return $.ajax(settings_3);
  }))
  .then(function(results) {
    // results is an array of all the query results, in an order matching
    // the original array
    auto_video_jobs_array = results;  // you might not need auto_video_jobs_array 
                                      // anymore, but just in case...
    that.setState({
      current_auto_video_jobs: results
    });
  });
```